# Multiple varbinds in SNMP packet

Tags: snmp

For an snmp packet, I've been following the template in figure 3 at this [link](http://www.rane.com/note161.html)

I want to send 3 different OID's with values to set and 1 save command in the same snmp packet, and am putting each oid-value pair in its own varbind. With the current packet, the set request is accepted and an identical get response is recieved. The packet sets the values and the save command is executed.

BUT, the problem is that each OID should have it's unique value set - as sent in the packet, but what is actually happening is that the value associated with the first OID in the packet is being set for the other two OID's and then saved.

I can set each OID and password individually, so I know the OID's are correct. When I put them all in the same varbind list, the values I expect to be set are not. Is there a reason that I am seeing this behavior?

Here is the packet I am sending:

```
30 81 b2                                                 [message type & length]
02 01 00                                                 [snmp version]
04 07 70 72 69 76 61 74 65                               [community type, length, string]
a3 81 a3 02 04 24 41 b7 40                               [pdu type, length, request id]
02 01 00 02 01 00                                        [error codes]
30 81 94                                                 [varbind list type and length]
30 26                                                    [#1 varbind item type and length]
06 0f 2b 06 01 04 01 ee 2d 02 02 09 01 15 01 0a 01       [#1 type, length and oid] 
04 13                                                    [value type and length]
41 6e 6e 69 6b 61 41 6e 6e 69 6b 61 41 6e 6e 69 6b 61 32 [value]
30 2f                                                    [#2]
06 0f 2b 06 01 04 01 ee 2d 02 02 0a 01 15 01 0a 01       [#2 oid]
04 1c                                                    [value type and length]
53 6f 6d 65 74 68 69 6e 67 53 6f 6d 65 74 68 69 6e 67 53 6f 6d 65 74 68 69 6e 67 32 [value]
30 26                                                    [#3]
06 0f 2b 06 01 04 01 ee 2d 02 02 0a 06 15 01 0a 01       [#3 oid]
04 13                                                    [value type and length]
41 6e 6e 69 6b 61 41 6e 6e 69 6b 61 41 6e 6e 69 6b 61 33 [value]
30 11                                                    [save command]
06 0c 2b 06 01 04 01 ee 2d 02 03 01 01 00                [save command oid length and oid] 
02 01 01                                                 [value type, length, value content]
```